# Apply CSS to child when parent contains class

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to get CSS applied to a child element of a parent that has a dynamic class. See example. Is there any solution to this?

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/0yjn925g/`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
 

[class^="wrapper-"] .username {background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-">
  <input class="username" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-a1">
  <input class="username" type="text"/>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-a2">
  <input class="username" type="text"/>
</div>
```